# Laravel: AJAX and back()

Tags: ajax, laravel, back

I am making a "editable table" without any javascript frameworks, just jQuery to load partial views (editable rows and read-only rows).

I would like, if possible, to use my default ValidationException handler for this. It simply does:

```
return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->withErrors($exception->validator->messages())
    ->withInput($request->all());
```

The problem is that the back() call returns not my latest requested editable row, but the entire page. I assume this is because AJAX-requests are not saved by Laravel as a "previous location", and thus not accessible via back(). Is there a way I can override this?

Edit to clarify question:

1. When the user clicks the "Edit"-button on a row the "editable row partial" is AJAX-requested and placed in document.
2. When the user AJAX-submits the editable row and a validation error happens I want the editable row partial to be returned again, this time with errors and old input. Just like a regular, non-AJAX failed form submission. This can be done manually by catching the exception and returning said view, but if possible I want to just use back() - and for that be possible I need the request from **1.** to somehow be pushed into Laravels stack of "previous locations".

Comment: A bit hard to understand your question. Do you want a JSON response instead?

Comment: The default `ValidationException` returns a json response when you make an ajax request and doesn't redirect. This should be sufficient for you to handle real time validation.

Comment: Edited question to clarify a bit.

The code snippet is what runs in my ExceptionHandler if a  ValidationException is caught - no default JSON-response is generated.

Comment: To clarify even more, I want to avoid doing any kind of templating in client - even appending error messages. Client should be really simple and just load partials.

Comment: I don't think that there is a solution for what you want. In case of errors you have to append those errors to the form. The inputs remain unchanged.